# How to reduce space between letters and fix rotated letters in this CAPTCHA

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, captcha

I am trying to get the text from rotated letters from images by using the Python `cv2` and `tesseract ocr` library but am unable to do that.

Input Image:

[image: Input Image]

My first approach to split into multiple letters and fix the rotate letter's and then extract the text which didn't works.

```
import cv2
from imutils import contours

image = cv2.imread('input_0.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts, _ = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 10:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = 255 - image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 1)
        ROI_number += 1
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output Getting:

[image: output generated by above code]

**Now**

I want to reduce the space between the letters and fix the rotated letters in the image but I am not getting any solution for the same.

**UPDATE**

Tried to rotate the letter by using below code but am unable

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnts[0])
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (36,255,12), 3) # OR
# cv2.polylines(image, [box], True, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Expected Output**

784FIK

Please suggest how to reduce the space between the letters and fix the rotated letters? then may be tesseract ocr works.

Comment: Hi. Right now your code doesn't show what you tried in order to read the characters. What did you do with tesseract that did not work out?
OCR can be a tricky field which is why preprocessing is usally the key to succeed. The characters you showed are not upright. Since you already managed to separate the characters maybe you can get an estimate about their rotation angle and to rotate them upright, character by character. Contrast and image quality seems to be fine to my eye, so my guess is that an OCR like tesseract should be able to read it after rotation.

Comment: @Flow, Yes tesseract predicting wrong text. Can you please suggest how to reduce the space between the letters and fix the rotated letters?

Comment: Use PaddleOCR. Be sure to install paddlepaddle first..

Comment: Get the contours for each letter. Then get the rotated bounding box (see cv2.minAreaRect()), which will tell you the rotation. You can then unrotated them.

Comment: or chuck tesseract (it's ancient tech) and train your own network on the captchas directly, no preprocessing/feature engineering

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz, Please share the details

Comment: if you want to break captchas, you're gonna have to do the work yourself. I find it unethical to "give" you captcha-breaking software. surely you just don't think that the commercially available captcha breaker programs are worth the money.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz, unethical ? Why? `https://2captcha.com/enterpage` please see the url. This company is providing API for captcha break. if its unethical how this company is running? As per my knowledge we can use the automation tool to get the public data. Its legal and ethical also.

Comment: that update, "rotate the letter by using below code", isn't supposed to rotate it. it's supposed to draw rotated boxes around each component. please understand code before you think it failed to do something it's not intended to do in the first place. since you took that from a posted answer that clearly states in a comment that they did the actual rotating step _manually_ in a picture editing program, you shouldn't be surprised about this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make some progress, though it seems to be unstable to me. You need to check with larger datasets.

```
image = cv2.imread('input_0.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = 255 -thresh

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts, _ = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")

ROI_number = 0
offset = 6
custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 10' # psm is crucial for the detection
# -> https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 10:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = image[y-offset:y+h+offset, x-offset:x+w+offset]
        
        angle = cv2.minAreaRect(c)[-1]

        # letters need to be rotated and placed into an image
        # with larger area to have enough space around the letters

        # I did this manually in ImageJ/Fiji, but it should also be possible in opencv.


        img_name = 'ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, ROI)
        print(pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, config=custom_oem_psm_config))
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 1)
        ROI_number += 1
```

The angle of an individual character needs to be corrected to 0° or 90°.
only the '4' needed to be rotated (result was 38°) by either nothing or towards 45°, I could not figure out why so far.

The image I generated with these angles + aligning the letters in ImageJ:
[image: imagej_characters.png]

This

```
custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 10'
image = cv2.imread('imagej_characters.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=custom_oem_psm_config))
```

was able to read 784FIK.

Hope this will help you to improve your results.

Comment: I have tried to rotate the letters but am unable to do that. Please check `cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnts[0])
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (36,255,12), 3) # OR
# cv2.polylines(image, [box], True, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()`